# Writing "reset" method, re-initializing objects not working - Java

Tags: java, reset, object-initialization

I have attempted to create a reset method by "re-initializing" the objects in question to new objects. What is happening is that some of the values stored in the objects are being reset, as per the constructors, yet some are not. Can anyone explain this?

```
  public void reset(){
    if(gameHasEnded){
      dicaprio = new CoolCat();
    }  
  }
```

above is an example of my reset method to reset the object below:

```
 public CoolCat(){
    area = LEO_START_AREA;  //rectangle object

    speed = 2 + (int)(5*Math.random());

    direction = RIGHT;     
  }
```

- direction and speed appear to get reset but the area does not

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: `LEO_START_AREA` is static?

Comment: yes `LEO_START_AREA` is `public static final Rectangle`

Comment: area should be initialized to the value of LEO_START_AREA

Comment: can you explain why this would not happen automatically as the constructor executes? i.e. if I run `new CoolCat()` why would the area not get re-assigned the static Rectangle `LEO_START_AREA`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using concurrency, then the first question to ask if its your reset method atomic (synchronized on some lock? or on `this` object, using default `synchronized` method modifier)? If its a simple singlethreaded program, then are you sure you are "resetting" the instance variable of your object to new objects themselves (if theyre not primitives that is), and not existing ones? Last but not least, in your reset just try setting the values to null (yourObjToRest=null;) before reinitializing them.

Edit: some code would be helpful to give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
public CoolCat(){
    area = LEO_START_AREA;
```

to

```
 public CoolCat(){
    area = new Rectangle(LEO_START_AREA);
```

and this fixed the problem completely.